# How to call a method in surrounding controller from button in ui-grid wrapped in custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

[tldr] How to make a button in a column template call a method from the controller surrounding the grid when the grid is wrapped in a custom directive? [ktxbye]

To explain, here's 3 plunkrs:

1. P1) Basic action column in ui-grid

   http://plnkr.co/edit/nYqZsKRYbTA0aFXVZOoV
2. P2) same but with Controller as vm

   http://plnkr.co/edit/b7x4Jjec5utkzSCrShMA
3. P3) wrapping ui-grid in my-grid (the action button doesn't work anymore)

   http://plnkr.co/edit/74AdcFywgNZgeGJn4nrb

In my app things are more complicated, and I did manage to make the button in the custom column call a method on the controller of my-grid (via `grid.appScope.vm.FunctionName`; in P3 above my-grid doesn't even have a controller, this is a simplified example), but figured I might be digging too deep in wrong directions, so...
how would you make the buttons in the grid column in P3 call the MainCtrl::Test method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from swalters (via ui-grid glitter chat), I think I have a decent answer.

[As documented](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope) ui-grid (3.x) uses isolated scopes but allows your templates to reach for the outer scope via `$scope.grid.appScope`.

What I did not realize is that when you set up your grid options, you can override what grid.appScope will return by setting the `appScopeProvider` option, and that this can be easily set to a scope you may have handy as you're constructing the grid.

Hence, for the scenario in my previous plunkrs, here's a solution by just adding `appScopeProvider: $scope` to the grid options

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/0THPYZXPmqhfWYGo2ebE
```